# Show that $\sum b_n$ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that $\sum b_n$ is divergent for $b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}a_r$ and nonnegative $a_r$ and not all $a_r$ are zero. I used comparison test:
$S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n a_r$ is partial sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and it's an increasing sequence. If $S_n\geq1$ $$ 0 < \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{S_n}{n}$$ and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent. So by comparison test, $\sum \frac{S_n}{n} = \sum b_n$ is divergent. but what if $S_n < 1$?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty a_r$ is constant in terms of $n$, so basically we are trying to decide whether $c\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ converges or diverges for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since you know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ diverges, perhaps you know that multiplying a divergent sum by a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ produces another divergent sum. Then you are finished.

Answer (score 1):

1) Say if $\sum a_r$ diverges, then you are done
2) Say if $\sum a_r$ converges. Then it is some non-zero constant. Since $\sum \frac 1 n$ diverges, $\sum \frac c n$ diverges for all constant c that is not zero.